# listening to an event during listening to another event in socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

Hi I'm developing a chatroom by socket.io and my problem is I want to listen to an event while I'm listening to another event but it wouldn't work, I was wondering if it is possible or not?

let me explain more with my code :

```
 //it is my first listener that get the message
         socket.on('send-private-message', async (data) => {
     io.to(receiverSocketId).emit('send-message-to-receiver', {
                message,
                currentChat: data.currentChat,
              });
    //Here I want to listen to another event but It would catch nothing
    socket.on('another event',data=>{})
    }
    }
```

Comment: You want to start listening to `another event` follow a `send-private-message` event, but when do you want to _stop_ listening to it? Or will you continue listening forever after the first `send-private-message`?

Comment: I want to listen forever actually, anytime a message is sent to the server this event will work

Comment: But after receiving a second private message, you register the same listener for the other event a second time. Why is that necessary?

Comment: every time I send a message from the server to the receiver if he was online and saw the message an emitter sends info that the receiver saw the message and the server must listen to this emitter and changes the message status to "seen" afterward sends the message to the sender. what can I do to catch this information before sending the message to the sender?